# Flutter error catch e.message not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

```
void createUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((value) => Get.offAll(Home()));
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("Error while creating account", e.message, //Error on e.message
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
    }
  }
```

> Error: The getter 'message' isn't defined for the class 'Object'. Try
> correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a
> getter or field named 'message'.

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Why don't you try to print `e` or add a breakpoint to check what does it contain?

Comment: Try printing the value of e to see what type it is?

Comment: Its type is FirebaseAuthException.
Printing it shows : [firebase_auth/invalid-email] The email address is badly formatted.
I want to avoid " [firebase_auth/invalid-email] " this from the output

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is the `e` object you are catching doesnt have the `message` property. You can see which type it is by using `print(e.runtimeType)`. If you want to catch some specific type of Exception, you should try:

```
try {
   // 
} on SomeClass catch (e) {
    print(e.message)
} catch (e) {
   // 
}
```

Comment: runtimeType is FirebaseAuthException .

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by adding `on FirebaseAuthException` before `catch` and converting `e.message` to `e.message.tostring()`

```
void createUser(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((value) => Get.offAll(Home()));
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("Error while creating account", e.message.toString(),
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
    }
  }
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer..

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by adding on `FirebaseAuthException` before catch and converting `e.message` to `e.message.tostring()`.